# Ionic 2 - run code inside app when receiving push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic2

I'm implementing push notifications in a Ionic 2 app for Android. For this, I'm using the following function:

```
registerPush() {
    this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
        return this.push.saveToken(t, {ignore_user: false});
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
        this.push.rx.notification().subscribe(msg => {
            // execute some code
        });
    });
}
```

With this, I'm able to receive push notifications sent from server. While the app is in foreground, the `execute some code` part is run without problems. While the app is in the background (I'm using the background plugin), the push notification is received, but when I click on it nothing happens.

I want to execute the notification code in this situation too, and open the app when I click it. Is there any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I've read the plugin documentation and changed the code accordingly:

```
registerPush() {
    this.pushNotifications = Push.init({ android: { senderID: "xxxxxxxx" } });

    this.pushNotifications.on('registration', data => {
        // send token to server
    });

    this.pushNotifications.on('notification', data => {
        // handle notification
    });

 }
```

With this, and with `content-available` set to 1 in the notification sent from server, the app executes the code whether I'm inside it or not.
However, I'm still not able to put it in foreground when I click the notification.

Comment: Which is the plugin that you are using . With this plugin , this scenario will be handled https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: Phonegap Plugin Plush, as described here: https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#plugin-installation

Comment: Im not sure plugin you mentioned. But recently we have used the plugin which I mentioned and in android it works as expected.

Comment: Apparently, it's the same one

Comment: I don't see your code for receive push, above just handle register.